# Informix and C#: Check for NULL or empty char returned by informix

Tags: c#, null, char, informix

From C# app I query to a database informix. Informix returns some fields. One of them is a character and this character can be returned as 'y', 'n', empty ('') or null so I need to check this field from C# in order to see whether it is null or empty in first place and then check for the two other possibilities 'y' or 'n'. I want to control it in order to avoid and exception when checking.

How can I do it from C#?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. To check if a string is null or empty you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty( theStringVarInQuestion )`

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? with a 2k+ rating you should know what you need to include to get sense from anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first statement you can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(YourStringHere)` to check its empty or null, then you can continue with 'y' or 'n' check

Comment: Yes, finally i have done a similar solution to yours: Convert.IsDBNull(dbField) == false && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dbField)) ? treat if 'y' or 'n' and return true or false respectively : null;